# jQuery toggle with different attributes and apply ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, toggle

I am using this jQuery plugin for making toggle, but I have an issue that when I make multiple toggles that have same ids and class so in that case I am not able to identify particular toggle for applying auto load ajax on changing value.
I would to ask that how I make same toggle with this same plugin but different ids or class or name so I make ajax function like when I click toggle it will update in PHP without submitting submit button.

The plugin I am using is [this one](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Tiny-On-Off-Switch-Button-Plugin-For-jQuery-easyswitch/)

The code I am using is this:

**HTML**

```
<p>Default: <span class="easyswitch"></span></p>
<p>Checked: <span class="easyswitch" data-default="1"></span></p>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>
    $('.easyswitch').easyswitch();
</script>
```

**AJAX**

```
$('MY_CLASS_NAME').change(function(){
    var mode= $(this).prop('checked');
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      dataType:'JSON',
      url:'test.php',
      data:'mode='+mode,
      success:function(data)
      {
        $("body").html('Operation Saved');
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not handle `easyswitch's change event`. you need to create `click event` of it, and from it you can get the status of current toggle.

```
    $('.easyswitch').easyswitch();

    $('.easyswitch').click(function () {

        var mode = $(this).hasClass('on');
        toogleStatus(mode);
    });

    // for all controlls.
    $(".easyswitch").each(function() {

       var mode = $(this).hasClass('on');
       toogleStatus(mode);

    });

   function toogleStatus(mode)
   {

       if (!mode) {
            alert('checked')
        }
        else {
            alert('unchecked')
        }
   }
```

Comment: what I will do if I have multiple toggle?

Comment: @ShubhamSingh, above code will work for all toogls.

Comment: But I wish to work per ids, and when I use toggle html it all have same class and ids How I make this seperate?

Comment: `$(this).hasClass('on')` this will give you value for current clicked toggle, if you want to get all `easyswitch` toggle value, you can check my updated code

Answer (score 0):

Try using `callback` option

```
$('.easyswitch').easyswitch({
  callback: function(val, ele) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      url: 'test.php',
      data: { mode: val },
      success: function(data) {
        $("body").html('Operation Saved');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: what I will do if I have multiple toggle?

Comment: works for all `easyswitch`. If you want only for one you can use `id` instead of class

Comment: But I wish to work per ids, and when I use toggle html it all have same class and ids How I make this seperate?

Comment: You are asking something irrelevant to the current question / answer. I hope the answer provided here is enough for this question.